# Excluding an ID from a global styling

Tags: css

I am setting the style of list items like so:

```
ul.list li {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    height: 20px;
}

ul.list li:hover {
    background: #F7F7F7;
}
```

but I want to define a special list item for the title of the list only it inherits the previously defined style too. I know I could just give the above styling a class but that feels cumbersome. Do I have to manually "undo" everything just for the special list item or give the above styling a class? or is there a better way to do it? Maybe I shouldn't be using a list item for the title?

```
ul.list li.header {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the title of the list must be inside the list, I'd probably just (as you mentioned) "manually undo" them:

```
ul.list li.header {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;

    background: transparent;
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
}
```

It's not so bad.

---

If you only need to support [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3), you could do this:

```
.list li:not(:first-child) {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    height: 20px;
}
.list li:first-child {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.list li:hover {
    background: #F7F7F7;
}
```

This eliminates the need for any classes (though you could replace `:first-child` with `.header` if you do want to keep that class).

Comment: I only really have to support Google Chrome so I'll try the CSS3 way, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're at liberty to use advanced CSS3 selectors, you can use the `:not()` selector:

```
ul.list li:not(.header) {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Otherwise, you'll just have to manually override them.

Comment: I'm pretty much making this for me to use so I can pretty much guarantee it will only been seen in Google Chrome. I'll play with CSS3. Thanks :)